# Can`t connect MySQL database in phpMyAdmin by python

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to use python to connect database in phpMyAdmin.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.0.0.140",port=80,user="root",passwd="password")
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
results=cursor.fetchall()
for result in results:
print row
```

and I get this error

```
2013,"Lost connection to MySQL server at'waiting for initial communication packet',system error:0"
```

I can access the database in chrome, so I don`t think it is a problem of remote access.

=======================update=======================

The real reason is that I am in a limited net segment.(maybe)

There is something wrong with SQL connection out of my code.

If changed code like this:(port is not needed)

```
MySQLdb.connect(host="10.0.0.140",user="root",passwd="password")
```

People in public net segment can connect the phpMyAdmin but I can`t.

I can not change my net segment so I can`t confirm it is the real reason.

But it is the only difference between me and others.

Comment: are you sure you run it at port 80 ?

Comment: Where is the database you are accessing located? Is it at your host somewhere or on your local machine?

Comment: I doubt it is run at port 80, this is the url to your phpMyAdmin and not the core mysql database server. Is this a hosted environment? Or do you run this in your local machine?

Comment: It is not in my local machine.I use http://XXX/phpmyadmin/ to access so I think port should be 80

Comment: You mean although there is no port in http address,the real port is not default 80 because it is not a real IP address to database server?

Comment: Then check your XXX and it will provide you a XXX jdbc url for your mysql, and be sure to grant access so you can logon to the mysql from your workstation. The mysql url/host would be something like NNNN-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd.xxx.domain.xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you should do it. phpMyAdmin serves HTML to the user and should be used in a Web browser. You should connect directly to the MySQL host which is usually listening on port :3306. Also, you should keep in mind that, in production, MySQL servers are ordinarily not listening on public interfaces.

Comment: You mean maybe the port is 3306? And the IP is not 10.0.0.140 because it is phpMyAdmin`s?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just an interface to the MySQL server, so you can not use it in your way.

Although, if the MySQL server is listening on the public network interface and the firewall accepts connections to that specific port, then you are ok and you can connect from the outer world to the port 3306.

Answer (score 3):

Check the connection, are you sure you run your mysql at port 80?

As I wrote in the comments, I doubt it runs port 80, this is the url to your phpMyAdmin and not the core mysql database server. Normally the web and database run on different machines, different IP addresses etc. Is this a hosted environment? Or do you run this in your local machine.

If it is your local machine then changing to port 3306 should work.

If it is a hosted environment by a hosting partner then you need to check the JDBC url from them. As you wrote it is XXXX hosted partner. Then check your XXX and it will provide you a XXX jdbc url for your mysql, and be sure to grant access to the user so you can logon to the mysql from your workstation remotly. The mysql url/host could be something like this NNNN-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd.xxx.domain.xx

Also did you try the [**PyMYSQL**](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(host='10.0.0.140',user='root',passwd='password')
cursor = db.cursor()
query = ("SHOW DATABASES")
cursor.execute(query)
for r in cursor:
print r
```

Comment: It seems I should ask IT to get real IP address and port.Thanks for answering so much! Hope I can do it with your help.